# Why can't my web client accept an image from my web server?

Tags: java, httpserver, simplehttpserver

I this is my java HTTP server:

```
public class WebServer implements Runnable {
    public static final int PORT = 80;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        HttpServer $server;
        try {
            $server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(80), 0);
        } catch (IOException _e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(_e);
        }
        $server.createContext("/", _httpExchange ->
        {
            String $uri = _httpExchange.getRequestURI().toString();
            $uri = $uri.startsWith("/") ? $uri.replaceFirst("/", "") : $uri;
            if ($uri.equals("")) {
                sendFile("test.html", _httpExchange);
            }
            else if ($uri.matches(".*\\.[^/.]+")) {
                sendFile($uri, _httpExchange);
            }
            else {
                sendFile($uri + ".html", _httpExchange);
            }
        });
        $server.start();
        System.out.println("Server started at " + getPrivateIp() + " on port " + PORT);
    }


    private static String getPrivateIp() {
        try (final DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket()) {
            datagramSocket.connect(InetAddress.getByName("8.8.8.8"), 12345);
            return datagramSocket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress();
        } catch (UnknownHostException | SocketException _e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(_e);
        }
    }
    public static void sendFile(String _name, HttpExchange _exchange) throws IOException {
        try {
            InputStream $stream = WebServer.class.getResourceAsStream(_name);
            if ($stream == null) {
                _exchange.sendResponseHeaders(404, 0);
                _exchange.close();
                return;
            }
            Scanner $scanner = new Scanner($stream).useDelimiter("\\A");
            String $response = $scanner.next();
            _exchange.getResponseBody();
            _exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, $response.getBytes().length);
            _exchange.getResponseBody().write($response.getBytes());
            _exchange.close();
        } catch (Exception _ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(_ex);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, and then open my website, everything is ok, but I cannot see any images. In the network tab, it says that the image was accepted, but it's not shown. I tried using `Files.copy()` in `sendFile()` method, but it didn't work - it didn't show the website, nor the image! (Not even when I did localhost/image.jpg).

In the network tab, it also shows that the MIME type is img/jpeg, which is correct, so it's not because of that...

Using wget, I get a normal looking .jpg file, but if I open it, it's corrupted...

Does someone know how to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you passing correct image file paths? Try any cdn images for testing this out.

Comment: @Kartikey in the original code i have some `System.out.prinln()` log calls, and everything is how it's supposed to be. The String $response is also full of characters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

You just check if the request wants .png or .jpg file (or you can just check the MIME type), and if it does, then you have to use `ImageIO` class

```
public static void sendFile(String _name, HttpExchange _exchange) {
        try {
            InputStream $stream = WebServer.class.getResourceAsStream(_name);
            if ($stream == null) {
                _exchange.sendResponseHeaders(404, 0);
                _exchange.close();
                return;
            }
            if (_name.matches(".*?\\.(png|PNG|jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG)")) {
                BufferedImage $image = ImageIO.read($stream);
                if (_name.toLowerCase().endsWith("png")) {
                    _exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, getImageSize($image, "png"));
                    ImageIO.write($image, "png", _exchange.getResponseBody());
                }
                else {
                    _exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, getImageSize($image,"jpeg"));
                    ImageIO.write($image, "jpeg", _exchange.getResponseBody());
                }
                $stream.close();
                _exchange.close();
                return;
            }
            Scanner $scanner = new Scanner($stream).useDelimiter("$");
            String $response = $scanner.next();
            _exchange.getResponseBody();
            _exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, $response.length());
            _exchange.getResponseBody().write($response.getBytes());
            _exchange.close();
        } catch (Exception _ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(_ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).